# Parameter not passing in curl using Php

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I am trying to fetch data from webservice(nodejs) using curl in php but i am getting result "lang is required"
  i tried with following code but not working for me where i am wrong ?
  Here is my code

```
$post = ['lang'=> "593f973dea53161779dd5660",'password'=> "amit123d"];
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url="http://xxxxxx:8000/api/employer/login";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $result = json_decode($response);
  echo "<pre>";print_R($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually to send post variables i use : the [http_build_query](https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.

```
$url = "http://xxxxxx:8000/api/employer/login";
$post = ['lang'=> "593f973dea53161779dd5660",'password'=> "amit123d"];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
echo "<pre>";print_R($result);
```

It works better.

Comment: Check your code with a the url of php file printing the $_POST variable. You will see it's working. Maybe the NodeJS webservice is waiting something different as lang in a POST or maybe a POST coming from some page only ....

Answer (score 0):

1. first check the request whether send post field or not.

```php
$post = ['lang'=> "593f973dea53161779dd5660",'password'=> "amit123d"];
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url="https://httpbin.org/post";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $result = json_decode($response);
  echo "<pre>";print_R($result);
```

the site: https://httpbin.org/ will response the post field if the post data exists.

2. I think the problem may occurs the nodejs side. Does it check the post field rightly ? 
   from my experience your code is right.

Comment: not working for me , showing "lang is required",what should i do ?